# Xcode 8, unable to run the app on device, suddenly there is an error "An invalid key was encountered"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I was able to run the app on device yesterday, and when I tried today, it started giving this error (Picture attached). 
I am able to run it on the simulator but not on the actual device. 
I changed nothing nor deleted any certificates or provisioning profiles. 
I have already tried cleaning the derived data. 
How do I remove this error ?

[image]

Comment: I do not understand, -1 ? Without telling me my mistake ? What did I do wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many tries, the only way I managed to get rid of the error was by checking the Automatically Manage Signing option. For that I had to log in to my apple account.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to reinstall pods to see if it fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it helps but I had the same problem. I could run on real device but not on simulator so opposite situation with yours. However for me the fix was to remove app from simulator anad remove caches. And reinstall it. I think it is Xcode 8 bug.

Other thing to try is like the other Filipe saied,to reinstall pods or atleast try to update them: `pod update`

Are you using KeyChain?

Comment: No. By keychain if you meant automatic code signing,then no. I manually installed the certificates and profiles. I do not have the access to the actual apple account. But it was working for the past one month or so. It happened suddenly.

Now I have tried your way, uninstalled the app from simulator and then tried to install the app on device, but the same error popped up. "An invalid key was encountered". 
I have also tried pod install. Will now try pod update.